# Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call - GWT 2.6

Tags: spring, gwt, gwt-rpc

I'm working with a GWT(2.6) project together with Spring using "gwtrpc-spring" lib.

I'm trying to send a POJO from server to client, I get this POJO instance getting a Spring bean, and works well, but when I try to send it to client, I got this exception:

```
[WARN] Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' was not assignable to 'com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable' and did not have a custom field serializer.For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find public method: setName with 0 params.
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:667)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:130)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter$ValueWriter$8.write(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:153)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:587)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponse(RPC.java:605)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:393)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:579)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:545)
    at org.gwtrpcspring.RemoteServiceDispatcher.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RemoteServiceDispatcher.java:100)
    at org.gwtrpcspring.RemoteServiceDispatcher.processCall(RemoteServiceDispatcher.java:64)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:305)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:960)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1021)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My POJO is:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable;

public class ApplicationItem implements Serializable, IsSerializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private long id;
    private String name;    
    private String path;
    private String grant;
    private String icon;

    public ApplicationItem(){}

    public void setId(long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setName()
    {

    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setPath(String path)
    {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public String getPath()
    {
        return path;
    }

    public void setGrant(String grant)
    {
        this.grant = grant;
    }

    public String getGrant()
    {
        return grant;
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon)
    {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public String getIcon()
    {
        return icon;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ApplicationItem: ["+this.id+", "+this.name+", "+this.path+", "+this.grant+", "+this.icon+"]";
    }
}
```

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you tried id after removing extra no argument `setName()` method?

Comment: Yes, in fact i added that method to try, but without it doesn't work too.

Comment: Are you using eclipse with built in Jetty server? Or are you using Tomcat server integrated with eclipse?

Comment: I'm using Jetty by default on eclipse.